# Haskell Flag Pattern

Tags: haskell

I'm a very new user to Haskell and have been thrown in the deep end with some work. I've been assigned the task to make a flag pattern function that produces something like this -

[Here is a link to the image of what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdf5o.png)
To describe it, its basically a hollow rectangle with an X in the middle produced with *'s

The only problem is I'm not too sure how to use haskell almost entirely, especially coordinates or even if-then-else.

Here's what I have so far, I'm pretty much stuck at the if then else part. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
flagpattern :: Int -> String
flagpattern a
  | a <= 4 = ""
  | otherwise = fill (grid a) a

grid :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
grid a = [(x, y)| x<- [0..a], y<-[0..a]]

fill :: [(Int, Int)] -> Int -> String
fill [(x:xs,y:ys)] a
if fst (x,y) == 0 then
    if snd (x,y) < a then "*" ++ fill [(xs,ys)]
    else "*\n" ++ fill [(xs,ys)]
else
    if fst (x,y) == a then
        if snd (x,y) < a then "*" ++ fill [(xs,ys)]
        else "*\n" ++ fill [(xs,ys)]
    else 
        if fst (x,y) + snd (x,y) == a then
            if fst (x,y) == a then "*\n" ++ fill [(xs,ys)]
            else "*" ++ fill [(xs,ys)]
        else " " ++ fill [(xs,ys)]
```

Comment: With respect, you haven't just been thrown in the deep end;  you've been tossed into the ocean.  You need a more general tutorial on Haskell if you can't do this.  I don't mean this disparagingly;  I would be very happy to be able to work in Haskell.

Comment: Note that an easier way to write `fst (x,y)` is `x` and an easier way to write `snd (x,y)` is `y`.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem I see with your posted code is the missing `=` in the definition of `fill` and the mis-indented body.  Fixing that:

```
fill :: [(Int, Int)] -> Int -> String
fill [(x:xs,y:ys)] a =   -- NOTE: need an `=` here
  -- NOTE: function body needs to be indendented
  if fst (x,y) == 0 then
      if snd (x,y) < a then "*" ++ fill [(xs,ys)]
      else "*\n" ++ fill [(xs,ys)]
  else
      if fst (x,y) == a then
          if snd (x,y) < a then "*" ++ fill [(xs,ys)]
          else "*\n" ++ fill [(xs,ys)]
      else 
          if fst (x,y) + snd (x,y) == a then
              if fst (x,y) == a then "*\n" ++ fill [(xs,ys)]
              else "*" ++ fill [(xs,ys)]
          else " " ++ fill [(xs,ys)]
```

gets rid of the parse error and introduces about a billion type errors.  In your definition of `fill`:

```
fill [(x:xs,y:ys)] a = ...
```

the first argument pattern is not the right way to match a list of tuples:

```
[(0,0),(0,1),...]
```

Instead, you want to peel off the first tuple from the rest like so:

```
fill ((x,y):rest) a = ...
```

and pass `rest` to the recursive `fill` calls.  You've also forgotten, I think, to pass the second argument `a` to the recursive `fill` calls.  After fixing that, your function looks like this:

```
fill :: [(Int, Int)] -> Int -> String
fill ((x,y):rest) a =
  if fst (x,y) == 0 then
      if snd (x,y) < a then "*" ++ fill rest a
      else "*\n" ++ fill rest a
  else
      if fst (x,y) == a then
          if snd (x,y) < a then "*" ++ fill rest a
          else "*\n" ++ fill rest a
      else
          if fst (x,y) + snd (x,y) == a then
              if fst (x,y) == a then "*\n" ++ fill rest a
              else "*" ++ fill rest a
          else " " ++ fill rest a
```

This type checks, though `flagpattern 7` crashes with an unmatched pattern after outputting somewhat incorrect output:

```
> flagpattern 7
"********\n      *      *      *      *      *      *      ********\n*** Exception: Flag.hs:(19,1)-(31,33): Non-exhaustive patterns in function fill
```

But maybe that'll help you keep working.

Also, note that in Haskell, the expression `[0..a]` includes both endpoints:

```
> [0..7]
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

so it's possible you want to use either `[0..a-1]` or `[1..a]` in `grid` with corresponding changes to the tests in `fill`, if you expect `flagPattern 7` to return a 7x7 grid instead of an 8x8 grid.